# Tinymce selects code

Tags: tinymce

On the tinymce editor there is this code

```
// Theme options

"styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
```

Are this select boxes

> styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect

part of a plugin or are they in a separate .js file.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way.I opened

> /var/www/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/editor_template.js

and i knew what advanced control was named for instance theme_advanced_blockformats:

This is the control with the block formats.To change their display names i put in this code

```
theme_advanced_blockformats : "Header 1=header1;Header 2=header2;Header 3=header3;Table Row=tableRow1",
```

and it worked.

There is that topic on tinymce website on `theme_advanced_styles` which serves as an excellent example http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:theme_advanced_styles